# BTC on blockchain

Tags: wallet, address, security, hash

I see my Wallet address on the Blockchain but it says spent and what does that mean? It did not arrive to the wallet i sent it too! I need it to be located and returned or sent to the wallet i gave.

Answer (score 1):

> **it says spent and what does that mean**

It typically means money was received in one transaction and later spent in a second, separate transaction. It is a historical record. You no longer have that money.

> **It did not arrive to the wallet i sent it too!**

It may be due to one of ...

- The transaction fee was too low and you need to be patient.
- Your receiving wallet isn't synchronised or has some other problem.
- You sent the money to a different address than the one you expected.
- The recipient is not telling you the truth.
- You are the victim of some sort of scam.

> **I need it to be located ...**

You can see the details of the spending transaction in any [blockchain explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer) by typing in the address and by typing in the transaction-Id of the transaction that spent the money.

Bitcoin is pseudo anonymous. This means you won't be easily able to identify a person or organisation associated with a receiving address. Without other information I doubt the recipient can be identified.

> **... and returned or sent to the wallet i gave**

Since Bitcoin transactions cannot be reversed, the only way this can happen is if you know the recipient and persuade them to make a third transaction that pays you a similar amount.

Beware people offering to get your money back for a fee, this is a favourite trick of scammers.